# When does SBCL replace the compiled function with newer version if that function is in use?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

For instance, if a loop is running that calls 'FOO at every iteration, and I recompile 'FOO before the loop exits, what happens?

What are the specific mechanism SBCL uses to handle such situations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SBCL is a compile-only implementation, so the answer to your question is easy to discover:

```
* (defun foo (x) (print x))

FOO
* (describe 'foo)

COMMON-LISP-USER::FOO
  [symbol]

FOO names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (X)
  Derived type: (FUNCTION (T) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
  Source form:
    (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA FOO
        (X)
      (BLOCK FOO (PRINT X)))

* (disassemble (lambda ()(loop repeat 10 do (foo 1))))

; disassembly for (LAMBDA ())
; Size: 91 bytes. Origin: #x1002F7F564
; 64:       BE14000000       MOV ESI, 20                      ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 69:       EB3E             JMP L1
; 6B:       0F1F440000       NOP
; 70: L0:   488BCE           MOV RCX, RSI
; 73:       4883E902         SUB RCX, 2
; 77:       488BF1           MOV RSI, RCX
; 7A:       488D5C24F0       LEA RBX, [RSP-16]
; 7F:       4883EC18         SUB RSP, 24
; 83:       BA02000000       MOV EDX, 2
; 88:       488975F8         MOV [RBP-8], RSI
; 8C:       488B057DFFFFFF   MOV RAX, [RIP-131]               ; #<FDEFINITION object for FOO>
; 93:       B902000000       MOV ECX, 2
; 98:       48892B           MOV [RBX], RBP
; 9B:       488BEB           MOV RBP, RBX
; 9E:       FF5009           CALL QWORD PTR [RAX+9]
; A1:       480F42E3         CMOVB RSP, RBX
; A5:       488B75F8         MOV RSI, [RBP-8]
; A9: L1:   4885F6           TEST RSI, RSI
; AC:       7FC2             JNLE L0
; AE:       BA17001020       MOV EDX, 537919511
; B3:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; B6:       F8               CLC
; B7:       5D               POP RBP
; B8:       C3               RET
; B9:       0F0B0A           BREAK 10                         ; error trap
; BC:       02               BYTE #X02
; BD:       19               BYTE #X19                        ; INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR
; BE:       9A               BYTE #X9A                        ; RCX
NIL
```

As you can see, the disassembly mentions `#<FDEFINITION object for FOO>` (as opposed to a the object `#<FUNCTION FOO>` returned by `(fdefinition 'foo)`), so, apparently, `fdefinition` is called on each iteration.

This can be confirmed by comparing these two disassmeblies:

```
* (disassemble (lambda () (fdefinition 'foo)))

; disassembly for (LAMBDA ())
; Size: 31 bytes. Origin: #x1002FF99F4
; 9F4:       488B15A5FFFFFF   MOV RDX, [RIP-91]               ; 'FOO
                                                              ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 9FB:       488B05A6FFFFFF   MOV RAX, [RIP-90]               ; #<FDEFINITION object for FDEFINITION>
; A02:       B902000000       MOV ECX, 2
; A07:       FF7508           PUSH QWORD PTR [RBP+8]
; A0A:       FF6009           JMP QWORD PTR [RAX+9]
; A0D:       0F0B0A           BREAK 10                        ; error trap
; A10:       02               BYTE #X02
; A11:       19               BYTE #X19                       ; INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR
; A12:       9A               BYTE #X9A                       ; RCX
NIL
* (disassemble (lambda () #.(fdefinition 'foo)))

; disassembly for (LAMBDA ())
; Size: 19 bytes. Origin: #x1003020214
; 14:       488B15A5FFFFFF   MOV RDX, [RIP-91]                ; #<FUNCTION FOO>
                                                              ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 1B:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; 1E:       F8               CLC
; 1F:       5D               POP RBP
; 20:       C3               RET
; 21:       0F0B0A           BREAK 10                         ; error trap
; 24:       02               BYTE #X02
; 25:       19               BYTE #X19                        ; INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR
; 26:       9A               BYTE #X9A                        ; RCX
NIL
```

the first definitely calls `fdefinition` and the second definitely does not, and the first is closer to the disassembly of the loop.

Finally, one can use the explicit test by Paulo Madeira:

```
(progn (sb-thread:make-thread (lambda () (sleep 5.1) (defun foo (x) (print (1+ x))))) 
       (dotimes (i 10) (sleep 1) (foo 1)))
```

starts showing 2.

Comment: That must be some kind of optimized `fdefinition` accessor, because `(progn (sb-thread:make-thread (lambda () (sleep 5.1) (defun foo (x) (print (1+ x))))) (dotimes (i 10) (sleep 1) (foo 1)))` starts showing `2`.

Comment: oops, I guess I misinterpreted the disassembly. sorry.

Comment: *the answer to your question is easy to discover*, but that has nothing to do with SBCL's compilation; as we've seen, it's not that easy based on the disassembly alone.  A more portable and simple test would suffice, e.g. `(dotimes (i 10) (foo 1) (when (= i 4) (defun foo (x) (print (1+ x)))))`.

Comment: Still, a compiler could infer that, since there's a redefinition of `foo` inside the loop, it would compile the call to `foo` using lookup by name instead of taking the function object before the loop.  Even with threads, the looping thread might not have seen the new definition without a proper memory barrier (depending on the architecture), but that is another topic.